# Spring MVC with OpenID - OpenIDAuthenticationFilter' not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying out Spring (using Spring Tool Suite and Tomcat v8.0) and wanted to make a login page, which will eventually become a "Log In via Google" feature.

I followed [this](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-integration.html) tutorial, and managed to get it up until the second part, where the user can sign in to view the home page. My only deviation is that I used a hard-coded username and password (as it will be replaced eventually, anyway).

**The Problem:**

At the point where `<form-login />` is to be replaced by `<openid-login />` is where things start to fail, with the following error:

[image]

The tutorial says nothing about this, and I get the same from other tutorials (such as [this one](http://blog.sandeepgupta.info/2013/04/integrating-web-application-with-openid.html))

Logs say this:

> Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference
>   to bean
>   'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while
>   setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception ....

Complete logs [here](http://pastebin.com/L9iGxRan).

Running the project gives this as a result:

[image]

Again, this happens upon changing `<form-login />` to `<openid-login />`

**My Codes:**

*secrity-app-context.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<!-- This is where we configure Spring-Security  -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/denied" >

 <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
 <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/home" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/> -->

 <form-login
   login-page="/login"
   authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"
   default-target-url="/home"/>

 <logout
   invalidate-session="true"
   logout-success-url="/login"
   logout-url="/logout"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
 <authentication-provider>
 <user-service>
 <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="admin" />
 <user name="user" password="user" authorities="user" />
 </user-service>
 </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

*LogInLogOutController.java*:

```
@Controller
public class LogInLogOutController {
    protected static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("controller");

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/login", "/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String getLoginPage(@RequestParam(value="error", required=false) boolean error, ModelMap model) {
      logger.debug("Received request to show login page");

      if (error == true) {
          model.put("error", "You have entered an invalid username or password!");
      } else {
          model.put("error", "");
      }
      return "login";
     }
}
```

*Login.jsp*:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Sonic: Log In</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    Log In To Sonic:
</h1>
<div id="login-error"> ${error} </div>
<form action="j_spring_security_check" method="POST">
    <p>
    <label for="username">User Name:</label>
    <input id="username" name="j_username" type="text" />
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input id="password" name="j_password" type="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
    </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

*web.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring/security-app-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Spring Security Filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And finally, the additions I made to *pom.xml*:

```
<!-- Spring Security -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-openid</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The fact that eclipse gives an error says nothing, have you actually tried running the code?

Comment: I'm using Spring Tool Suite. Yes, I have - The internal web browser returns an even less helpful "The Requested resource is not available.". This does not happen with the `<form-login />`.

Comment: STS is eclipse with a bunch of plugins it is still Eclipse underneath. The error probably indicates that your application didn't start or the filter is working but not redirecting correctly. Enable debug logging for `org.springframework` and see what happens.

Comment: Please add full stack trace (using the proper code tags and not quote tags!) currently the interesting part is missing. Also please specify which versions you are using.

Comment: Are you referring to the error logs from the console? I believe it will be too long to post, but I can put it up on pastebin.

Comment: Here: http://pastebin.com/L9iGxRan

Comment: Have you actually read that stack trace? The error in there is quite clear it cannot found certain classes. Looking at your pom snippet you are mixing Spring Security versions (one is using the `${org.springframework-version}` the other `${spring-security.version}` versions of the different frameworks don't align.)

Comment: Yes, I have read it. I'm wondering WHY it can't find the class, when I followed the tutorial - which said nothing about adding the class. As for the  Spring Security versions, I've changed them all to `${org.springframework-version}`. No dice.

Comment: As mentioned spring and spring security have different versions, you might run into compatibility issues right now!. Also you haven't mentioned which version(s) you are (trying) to use.